# Deletehash api imgur

Tags: laravel, imgur, livewire-3

How do I get the deletehash of an image that I already uploaded, to later delete it using the imgur api? I am using livewire from Laravel.

Comment: You should get object response when image is uploaded. `deleteHash` should be in there.

Comment: That's right, but the thing is that normally the deletion is done some time later, so that's when you lose that data from the deletehash

Comment: In other words, you haven't save `deleteHash` on upload? Concept should be saving `deleteHash` in one field as much as image id is saved in other field. Unfortunately, I don't have the answer if it can be deleted without `deleteHash`.

Comment: [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579669/imgur-delete-image-via-api)